# Vercel stopped correctly displaying images

Tags: file-upload, github-pages, vercel

I have been building a personal website using github pages and then deploying with Vercel.
For the last month I've had no issues uploading pictures, but from today all new images only show as an icon, and when inspected with Devtools I get the error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT.

The file paths are correct, because I'm able to see everything fine when I open the html file locally, so the issue must be in deployment. Also, I tried re-inserting old images that used to deploy correctly and I'm getting the same result.

I tried manually uploading the images to the github repository with "add-file" but still no luck.
Any idea what might be causing this?